# merge csv files for varying columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have multiple CSV files containing information element and their values. The length of these element and their values is not static and varies file to file. I want to merge them in a single CSV file with tabular representation of element and its value. For example below are the 3 CSV files -

1.CSV

```
a   b   c   d
1   2   7   6
```

2.CSV

```
a   b   d
5   6   7
```

3.CSV

```
a   b   b   c
33  7.2 0   8
```

Expected Output

Merge.csv

```
filename    a   b   b   c   d
1.CSV       1   2   ""  7   6
2.CSV       5   6   ""  ""  7
3.CSV       33  7.2  0  8  ""
```

I have tried this with awk/bash without success. Let me know how this can be done using awk. Thanking in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly wrap your code in CODE TAGS a button while editing `{}` and let us know then.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: your 3.csv file has two "b" columns, how do you know the first one will match the other "b" columns?

Comment: The repetition is present in some of the files. So, presenting the values for column "b" in the first one would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the problem that you've got 2 columns with the same name and using csv separated with commas, this code should help.

Let's say that the csv files have this format

```
a,b,c,d 
1,2,7,6
```

Then

```
sep=","
for file in $(ls -1 *.csv); do
    cols=$(head -n1 $file| grep -o $sep | wc -l | xargs echo "1+" | bc )
    for col in $(seq 1 $cols);do
        colName=$(head -n1 $file | cut -d$sep -f$col)
        [ ! -f  results/$colName ] && echo $colName > results/$colName
        sed 1d $file | cut -d$sep -f$col >> results/$colName
    done
done

paste -d"," results/* >  output.csv
```

UPDATED
try the following, this time I used the CSV files just as you put it on your example and by removing the duplicated column replaccing it by the letter "e"

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create files for headers
head -q -n1 *.csv | tr "," "\n" | sort -u > results/headers

# Create separated files with datas
while read _header; do 
  touch results/$_header
done < results/headers

# Create Final file with headers
echo -n "filename," > results/merge.csv
paste -s -d"," results/headers  >> results/merge.csv

# For each file; 
for _file in $(ls -1 *.csv); do
  cols=$(head -n1 $_file | tr "," "\n" | wc -l)
  echo -n "$_file," >> results/merge.csv

  for _col in $(seq 1 $cols); do
    _fileToWrite=$(head -n1 $_file | cut -d"," -f$_col)
    echo -n "$_file," >> results/$_fileToWrite
    sed 1d "$_file" | cut -d"," -f$_col >> results/$_fileToWrite
  done

  while read _header; do 
    data="$(grep $_file results/$_header | cut -d"," -f2)"
    echo -n "$data," >> results/merge.csv
  done < results/headers

  echo  >> results/merge.csv
done
sed -i 's/,$//g' results/merge.csv
```

RESULT

```
filename,a,b,c,d,e
1.csv,1,2,7,6 ,
2.csv,5,6,,7 ,
3.csv,33,7.2,8,,0
```

Comment: Thanks David. It is close to what I wanted but still I am not getting the desired output.cat output.csv
 
a,b,c,d

1,2,7,6

5,6,8,7

33,7.2,,

,0,,

The repetitive column "b" is missing in final output file. Also the values are not place correctly for 2.csv and 3.csv.

Comment: Afaik you should not have the same header twice in a csv, that is non sense, is it?

Comment: David, in a way you are right. 

Actually I am trying to arrange xml contents in csv file by parsing. Original XML has childs as Headers,Types and Values. Mostly if there are 5 types defined under one header we have 5 corresponding values. But sometimes the values gets repeated twice for the same 5 types defined.

Comment: David, I tried without duplicate headers by removing repeating "b" column in 3.csv but still it doesn't worked. Actually, for the second file we get value 8 inserted .. 5,6,8,7

Comment: You left the comas in your csv files, are they separated by comas or by spaces? This last code expected spaces

Comment: David, files are separated by commas. Example files 1.csv/2.csv/3.csv was only for easy reference. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've done the modifications, try now, still in the updated code part. it should work ok

Comment: Yes Perfect..Thanks David.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to close this question.

Comment: Hi David, 

The above code has some time complexity issue when executed for files having 1500 columns.

Comment: Hi, interesting... What kind of?